# Is there a standard distribution of minifigs when you purchase an entire case?

Tags: collectable-minifigures

The last couple of times I purchased a case of collectable minifigures, each one had three complete sets (16 x 3), plus an extra 12 remainder of random minifigs. My last case I ordered only had two complete sets, and the remainder of minifigs had a much wider variance (five of one minifig, none extra of others).

Should each case contain three sets, or is it truly random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every box contains the same distribtion of minifigs. For example see this review on [www.eurobricks.com](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=99986) of series 13 has the same distribution as my box. (links to his other CMF reviews are on the bottom of the first post)

For most series boxes contains 3 full sets and 12 remaining ones.

Series 9, 10 & 11 contain only 2 complete sets, with 2, 4 or 6 bags of the same minifigs. These boxes where also available as 'half' with only 30 bags. This way these boxes contains 1 complete serie.

Comment: Ok so basically with a box of 60, there should be at least two complete sets, but not guaranteed to be three?

Comment: Based on the current released boxes yes. At the moment its 3 sets again. Both Simpsons series and series 12 & 13 have 3 complete sets.